# How make dataframes with loop row? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get some new dataframes from one by column "day_of_week". Can I automate this process with loop row?

```
grouped = sleep.groupby('day_of_week')
    
monday    = grouped.get_group(0).loc[:, 'df']
tuesday   = grouped.get_group(1).loc[:, 'df']
wednesday = grouped.get_group(2).loc[:, 'df']
```

Sample of Data:

```
          Date  Sleep  Hours  Alimem  DoW
8  2020-01-09      4    9.6       0    3
9  2020-01-10      0    4.8       0    4
10 2020-01-11      0    0.0       0    5
11 2020-01-12      0    0.0       0    6
13 2020-01-13      0    7.2       0    0
14 2020-01-14      0    7.2       0    1
15 2020-01-15      0    7.2       0    2
16 2020-01-16      3    7.2       0    3
17 2020-01-17      0    6.4       0    4
18 2020-01-18      0    2.4       0    5
19 2020-01-19      0    2.4       0    6
20 2020-01-20      0    7.2       0    0
21 2020-01-21      0    7.2       0    1
22 2020-01-22      3    7.2       0    2
23 2020-01-23      0    7.2       0    3
24 2020-01-24      0    6.4       0    4
25 2020-01-25      0    3.2       0    5
```

Comment: Pls post a sample of your data

Comment: Data was added in the Question

Comment: Is your data only one week, or multiple weeks? If it's only one week, you can directly do [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). If it's multiple weeks, you need to post a more complete sample.

Comment: And what ultimate output do you want? *"get some new dataframes"* says nothing. Do you an aggregation or summary statistics (e.g. *"total hours slept on Mondays"* or *"average hours skept on weekend days"*)? or something else?

Comment: `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.day_name())))` should give you a dictionary of weekdays and subsets of the dataframe if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```py
days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']
grouped = sleep.groupby('day_of_week')
groups = {days[i]: grouped.get_group(i).loc[:, 'df'] for i in range(len(days))}
```

Comment: Following your path, I get the "dict" data type. Is it possible to collect individual data frames and access them by the names of the days of the week?

Comment: You'll be able to access them like so: `groups['mon']`

Comment: Please, may I ask you one another question? Your path works, but, I am a beginner and totally don't understand, how it works in the details. Please, explain me. Does this code create a dict? Why?

Comment: It uses dictionary comprehension, which creates a dict with keys as the name of week day and values as their respective dataframe. So it is like `{'week_day': DataFrame }`